# Export Tabs To Workbook Location or Downloads Folder

Tags: excel, vba

For the below macro, it is set to export specific sheets in my workbook as .csv files. It works great, however it saves to the last "save as" location, which can be difficult to find at times.

Is it possible to have it export to the downloads folder instead? I'm having trouble modifying the code to work properly, errors for days.

Thank you in advance!

Here it is as it stands now:

```
Sub SaveFinalV2()
Worksheets("Exclde Location Upload Template").Visible = True
Worksheets("Exclde Supplier Upload Template").Visible = True
Worksheets("Item Upload Template").Visible = True
Worksheets("User File Upload Template").Visible = True
Dim wsa As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
For Each wsa In Sheets(Array("Exclde Location Upload Template", "Exclde Supplier Upload Template", "Item Upload Template", "User File Upload Template"))
wsa.Copy
   Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
   With newWb
      .SaveAs wsa.Name & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YY at hh mm AMPM"), xlCSV
      .Close (False)
   End With
Next wsa
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
Worksheets("Exclde Location Upload Template").Visible = False
Worksheets("Exclde Supplier Upload Template").Visible = False
Worksheets("Item Upload Template").Visible = False
Worksheets("User File Upload Template").Visible = False
Worksheets("Eligible Items (If Applicable)").Visible = False
MsgBox ("All tabs have been exported, please check your [Save As] folder")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to theuser's `Downloads` folder using `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\"` and use that when saving the CSVs.

Obviously you can change `strSavePath` to any valid path.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveFinalV2()
Dim wsa As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook
Dim strSavePath As String

    Worksheets("Exclde Location Upload Template").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Exclde Supplier Upload Template").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Item Upload Template").Visible = True
    Worksheets("User File Upload Template").Visible = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    ' set the path to save CSVs to the user's downloads folder
    strSavePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\"
    
    For Each wsa In Sheets(Array("Exclde Location Upload Template", "Exclde Supplier Upload Template", "Item Upload Template", "User File Upload Template"))
        wsa.Copy
        Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
        With newWb
            .SaveAs strSavePath & wsa.Name & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YY at hh mm AMPM"), xlCSV
            .Close (False)
        End With
    Next wsa
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    
    Worksheets("Exclde Location Upload Template").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Exclde Supplier Upload Template").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Item Upload Template").Visible = False
    Worksheets("User File Upload Template").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Eligible Items (If Applicable)").Visible = False
    
    MsgBox ("All tabs have been exported, please check your [Save As] folder")

End Sub
```